# cross domain cookie with openid connect

Tags: cross-domain, openid, cookie

my app allows users to login with openid connect on a openid provider site in [www.domain1.com/login](http://www.domain1.com/login), when the user(me in this case) directly calls that url i can see that the browser sees a SESSION_IDP cookie.
But when i use c# Redirect.Request(thaturlabove) to redirect the user to that login page i do not see that cookie which appears to be a cross domain problem.
The redirect is initiated from [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com) as that is where the relaying party for openid is hosted.

whats a common solution to this?

this one:
https://github.com/contently/xdomain-cookies
reads like it could do the trick.....but im probably not the first guy to run into this problem. Isn't there a easier solution?

Comment: Programming questions should be asked on our sister site [so].

Comment: should i just copy the question over? i think the cross domain part / openid connect thingie is more of a network issue

Comment: We can't really help you to deal with network issues in your code, though.